# nginx getting files from different server

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a bunch of devices and I want to create a reverse proxy to go to the websites of these devices which are hosted on their IP. The problem is that when I get redirected to the site nothing loads in because the website is trying to get the files (css, js) from localhost instead of the device IP.

How can I change the destination of these calls?

I'm using nginx and this is the config file I use:

```
server {
    listen 3000;
    server_name localhost;

    location /device {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.159/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

    location /other-device{
        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.162/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
    error_log /var/log/nginx/debug.log debug;
}
```

Comment: I think you would be better off using multiple server{} blocks for each device.